# Highlight SQL queries inside of YAML file in Goland

Tags: jetbrains-ide, goland

Goland has a beautiful highlighting mechanism for SQL queries in Go code.

It looks like this:

[image]

You can use auto complete option to specify columns and table names. But if you'll move all you queries to configuration file (yaml file in my case), Goland stops highlighting your SQL queries.

[image]

Is there an option to enable SQL query highlighting for any specified file type?

Comment: I don't think this is related to the language, this is more of IDE thing, check if Jetbrains IDE have syntax highlight plugin for SQL.

Comment: @mamounothman, U are right. I have already removed go and yaml tags. Thx.

Comment: They say it's fixed (see this ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-51664) .. but I do not see how I can create custom Language Injection rule for YAML file... You can only inject it manually / temporarily .. but I guess it will not be super convenient for you. In any case: place caret inside such string, invoke Quick Fix menu (`Alt+Enter` on Windows/Linux) and choose "Inject language or reference" option.

Comment: @LazyOne, It works! Thx. You can write your solution in answer, and I'll accept It.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accordingly to this [IDEA-51664 ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-51664) you should be able to create a custom Language Injection rule in YAML files .. but I personally do not see how it can be done.

---

At the same time, you can manually inject any language into a value string inside the YAML file. It will be a temporal injection though (will last for one session or so). For this:

1. Place caret inside such string
2. Invoke "Quick Fix / Show Context Actions" menu (<kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> on Windows/Linux in most keymaps)
3. Choose `Inject language or reference` action

   [image]
4. Select desired language from a list (use `SQL` to inject current SQL Dialect for that scope (file/folder) or just `Generic SQL` if you do not need specific DB checks etc).

   [image]
5. Final result:

   [image]

Comment: This is a very useful answer and It solves that problem. ALT + ENTER works in Mac OS too. Thx